# Iphone: unable to show photos using AlAssetsLibrary

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, photos, alassetslibrary

I currently sending ipa to friends for testing. Funny thing is, one of my tester able view her photos stored on her phone which was running IOS 5 using iPhone 4.

Another 2 testers: one has iPhone 4 (IOS 4.3.3) , and iPhone 3GS (IOS 5.0.1) both of them can't see photos stored on their phone.

These are the code I have used:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if(result != NULL) {
        //NSLog(@"See Asset: %@", @"ggg");
        [assets addObject:result];

    }
};

NSLog(@"location = %i      length = %i ", range->location, range->length );

void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if(group != nil) {

        NSRange  *datarange = malloc(sizeof(NSRange));

        range->total = [group numberOfAssets];
        datarange->location = [group numberOfAssets] - range->location - range->length;
        datarange->length = range->length;
        NSLog(@" total = %i", range->total);

        int location = [group numberOfAssets] - range->location - range->length;

        if (location < 0)
        {
            datarange->location = 0;
            datarange->length = [group numberOfAssets] - range->location;
        }

        NSIndexSet *indexset = [ [NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexesInRange:*datarange];

        [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:indexset options:NULL
                             usingBlock:assetEnumerator];

        [indexset release];
        free(datarange);

        [self loadAssetToScrollView:assets]; 

    }

};    

    [assets release];

    assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                           usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                         failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                             NSLog(@"Failure");
                         }];

    [library release];
```

I saw somebody say about asynchronous thing in some other threads but don't know is it the case. He say put dispatch_async in the enumerate group block.

Does anyone know what is wrong.

Additionally, one of tester with iOS 4.3.3 can show his photos after enabling location services under General->Setting. Why we have to enable it? Can we enabled it on code since it will be quite disturbing to the user who using our application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is incredibly frustrating, but that is how it is, and you cannot enable location services in code (that is a good thing though).

Answer (score 3):

Also on iOS 5.x you must retain your `ALAssetsLibrary` instance so long as you need to work with the collected assets. When you release your `ALAssetsLibrary` instance like in your code just after calling `[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:…]` all the collected assets will be invalid.

See also the `ALAssetsLibrary` doc - overview:

> "… The lifetimes of objects you get back from a library instance are tied to the lifetime of the library instance. …"

Comment: Sorry a late reply, I am not quite understand. Do you mean if I tried to stored the AlAssets for later use, these AlAssets will be null or something similar. On my code, I only interested to the url of the ALAssets object so I only keep the url rather than the object itself. So do i still need to care about the lifetime of the object.

Comment: These collected assets instances will get nil-ed values (or something similar), yes. If you are only interested in asset's url, then collect only these urls. You shall use them later in [assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:] method to retrieve the asset object back again. The whole thing looks like Core Data with Managed Object Context (MOC) and ALAssetsLibrary instance looks like this MOC instance. So in Core Data when you "dismiss" this MOC instance you can't access to the data behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the first block `^assetGroupEnumerator` to the heap by `[[<#block#> copy] autorelease]`. Why? Because this block would be autoreleased by the runloop, if there are many assets need to be enumerated through.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing: don't use [self loadAssetToScrollView:assets]; inside the block but get the weak reference of self before the block like this:

```
__block YourExampleClassInstance *weakSelf = self;
```

and further use this weakSelf instance inside the block:

```
[weakSelf loadAssetToScrollView:assets];
void (^assetGroupEnumerator)… = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
…
};
```

Why? To avoid retain cycles.

Comment: Don't you mean `__weak` (or `__unsafe_unretained` on iOS 4) instead of `__block`?

Comment: Can you give me a reason of this? Sorry I am quite a new to objective-c, i still have a lot to learn. :(

Comment: @MarkAdams Hi Mark, currently I'm still don't using ARC. But with ARCed projects you are absolutely right.

Comment: @Simon Hi Simon, I suggest you watch Apple's WWDC2011 Session 308, especially at the time point 38:20 "What Does Block_copy() Not Do?" slide. There will be excellently explained the problem about retain cycles.